# How do i upgrade my magento 2.1.0 to lastest version?

Tags: magento2, upgrade

I have a testing site (magento 2.1.0) run in my windows with xampp, how do i upgrade to lastest version?

just tried composer update but

```
  Problem 1
    - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.1.5 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.1.5].
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.1.5 requires ext-xsl * -> the requested PHP extension xsl is missing from your system.

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\xampp\php\php.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

what is the meaning of " Problem 1
    - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.1.5 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.1.5]."?

Answer (score 0):

Update the version number in your `composer.json` and run `composer update`.

```
"require": {
  "magento/product-community-edition": "2.1.5",
  ...
```

Comment: question updated

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the PHP ext-xsl extension. I'm not sure how xampp works, but I'm assuming there is an option somewhere that allows you to enable certain PHP extensions (like GD and stuff). Look for ext-xsl (or most likely php-xml) in that list and enable it.

Answer (score 0):

For upgrading you magento you will need to follow following steps ;

- Sign up with magento [here](https://account.magento.com/applications/customer/create/)
- Get your authentication keys by following steps mentioned
  [this](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/comp-mgr/prereq/prereq_auth-token.html)
  article .
- Follow [this](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/comp-mgr/upgrader/upgrade-start.html) article to download your update and install it.